# Python : using a loop, read and save data to different lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to create a loop which reads  data from multiple  .txt files and save it to different lists (according to these different .txt files).

I don't know how to create the following lists (or np.arrays) in a loop: time1, time2, .. timeN, where N is a number of .txt files to analyze. 
I used the following to connect the 'constant' time and the 'variable' number: obj['time'+str(shot)], but it is not saved as a variable.

```py
import numpy as np
import os

for shot in  range(1,10):   
    #get the first txt:
    txt_file = os.path.join(path,'shot'+str(shot)+'.txt')
    #get data from txt:      
    data = np.genfromtxt(txt_file, skip_header = 4) 
    # now save it to the list (or np.array):
    obj['time'+str(shot)] = np.array([row[0] for row in data])
```

As an output I want to have 10 lists or arrays with time to work with them in future.

Comment: Make an empty list before the loop then append the arrays to it in the loop?

Comment: wwii could you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either empty list or empty dictionary to save your results.

In the first case, you should create an empty list first and next append data. Hence, *i-th* element in the list would corresponds to *(i+1)-th* source file.

```
import numpy as np
import os

my_data = []
for shot in  range(1,10):   
    #get the first txt:
    txt_file = os.path.join(path,'shot'+str(shot)+'.txt')
    #get data from txt:      
    data = np.genfromtxt(txt_file, skip_header = 4) 
    #append data
    my_data.append(data)

first_source_data = my_data[0]
```

Second option for you, if you want to have an access using filename.

```
import numpy as np
import os

my_data = {}
for shot in  range(1,10):   
    #gen filename
    filename = 'shot'+str(shot)+'.txt'
    #get the first txt:
    txt_file = os.path.join(path, filename)
    #get data from txt:      
    data = np.genfromtxt(txt_file, skip_header = 4) 
    # now save it to the list (or np.array):
    my_data[filename] = data

first_source_data = my_data['shot1.txt']
```

Comment: thank you Greeser. The problem is that for every shot there are 5 columns saved from data. What if I want to save only two and have separate access to these columns?

Comment: Just replace `my_data[filename] = data` to `my_data[filename] = data[:, [1,3]]`to extract desired columns (one and three). After that, you have an access as follows: `my_data[filename][:, 0]` and `my_data[filename][:, 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little confusing. But if I understand correctly.

You actually don't want to use list but dictionary. Dictionary is list in which you use keywords to access saved data(oversimplified)

If that is true need to put `obj = dict()` before for.
Or `obj = []` if you want to use list

And correct last line for dict is

```
obj['time'+str(shot)] = data[0]
```

Or with list

```
obj[shot] = data[0]
```

Comment: I would like to be able to addres the saved columns separately. If I use obj, I can not do this.
Also in your code the rows are saved in time+shot, not columns

Comment: Just change data[0] to for data[:][shot] .
than you access them with obj["time0"] or obj[0] for first column